# Is long.GetHashCode reliable cross environments

Tags: .net, gethashcode

Will the value that comes out of `long.GetHashCode()` be reliably the same across different .NET Framework-versions, OS-versions, processor-architecture and so on?

The question is based on [other questions that mentions different results on different servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114772/gethashcode-gives-different-results-on-different-servers).

```
// Will I be the same everywhere?
var hash = 2170881568869167279.GetHashCode();
```

**Bonus**: Does the same go for `int` and `uint`?

Comment: You'll never get an answer here that says it is okay.  That would be a very courageous answer.  But yes, GetHashCode is stable for Int32, UInt32 and UInt64.  They are very simple, no need to ever tinker with them like String.GetHashCode().

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the comment. Add a real answer with a link and I'd vote for it. We'll see which I find to be the correct after a while.

Comment: @HansPassant: But at least for `UInt64`, it can't be used to define identity, because `GetHashCode` always returns an `int`. So there will be collisions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the contract of `GetHashCode`, it is not even required to be the same on the same machine in two different processes:

> the default implementation of this method must not be used as a unique object identifier for hashing purposes.

For certain types it could be - and probably is - implemented in a way that will always return the same hash code, even on different machines. But that is an implementation detail you should *not* rely on - it could change without notice.

Furthermore, two different objects can legally have the same hash code. In your example with `long`, on average you will have each hashcode `long.MaxValue / int.MaxValue` times when you create the hashcode for all values from `long.MinValue` to `long.Maxvalue`.

**Conclusion:**
No, it is not a reliable way to identify an instance of an object.

When dealing with numbers, you could simply use the number itself or use a real hashing algorithm.

Comment: +1. "it could change without notice." And did, as I recall, between two different .NET versions. At least once.